Hide unmasked areas Blender 4.2 API
in Blender 4.2 they removed the MASKED option from the operator
bpy.ops.paint.hide_show(action='HIDE', area='MASKED')
What is the alernative to use?

bpy.ops.paint.hide_show_masked(action='HIDE')
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.paint.html#bpy.ops.paint.hide_show_masked

Hide/show all masked vertices above a threshold
Parameters:
action (enum in ['HIDE', 'SHOW'], (optional)) –

Visibility Action, Whether to hide or show vertices

    HIDE Hide – Hide vertices.

    SHOW Show – Show vertices.


